# ssh ignore special character

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm on an RHEL server trying to SSH to a windows server using the following command -

```
ssh -p 5950 -i /home/svcacct/.ssh/serverkey svcacct@servername prog Alias=database add -a blah -p "var1=shared_data\Repost, var2=1771, var3=1000 - S&P Index Summary, var4=SP, var5=20150129"
```

It then fails with the following message -

'P' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

The reason seems to be that linux is using the '&' as a special character which I don't want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to escape some quotes:

```
ssh -p 5950 -i /home/svcacct/.ssh/serverkey svcacct@servername prog Alias=database add -a blah -p "var1=shared_data\Repost, var2=1771, var3=\"1000 - S&P Index Summary\", var4=SP, var5=20150129"
```